# Error installing Ruby 2.3.0 via RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

```
    root@bubbling-brook:/# gem update --system
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 11 column 52 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:245:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:333:in `load_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:198:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `do_configuration'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:39:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone help me with this error. I am trying to install this on the remote server and bumping my head with this error. I have installed ruby successfully but rails is giving me issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check your **rvm**, if not found try to use:

```
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
```

To load the RVM.

Finally, you can use the suggested installation of @MattW.

Comment: What if the user is using zsh? Or fish? Or tcsh? Or another shell? Also, this has no relation to the asked question.